# Finding values of other functions with the help of given function

Tags: functional-equations

To all the viewers , I am really sorry That I didn't used Mathjax as I really don't know how to use it but will learn using it in the future :)
[image]

So , the problem I am facing it is that I used 2  methods which is cross multiplying , assuming values and putting them in this question but nothing is really helping me out  , What would be the best approach to reach  the answer of this question ?
Thank you

Comment: Hint: $f'(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: @Gerd  , Sir can you please tell how to reach to that step ?

Comment: Take the inequality and divide by $|x-y|$. Then for fixed $x$ take the limit $y \to x$.

Comment: @Gerd , Got it sir ! Thanks alot

Comment: @Gerd , Sorry to disturb you sir , after solving this question by the method you suggested do we have to take  x as x+h and if we have to do this what's the reason behind it ? Thank you

Comment: You can set $y=x+h$ and consider $h \to 0$ or you can consider $y \to x$. In both cases you get the derivative of $f$ at $x$.

Comment: @Gerd , Got it sir , Thank alot :)